# Apache Limiting proxypass based on http method

Tags: apache

I am very new to apache and I have two services one for read and one for writes and both services support same locations. But this routing does not seem to work. Is there anyway I can restrict these based on Http methods

```
 <VirtualHost *:1000>
     ServerAdmin me@example.com
     DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
     ServerName localhost:1000
     ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
     ForensicLog "logs/forensic-log.log"
     ProxyRequests Off
     ProxyPreserveHost On
  LogLevel debug
     <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
         
     </Proxy>

     #ReadService only supports GET
     <Location /api/users>
         ProxyPass        http://localhost:5000/api/users connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
         ProxyPassReverse hhttp://localhost:5000/api/calls
     </Location>
     
     #WriteService anything other than GET
 
     <Location /api/users>
         ProxyPass        http://localhost:7000/api/users connectiontimeout=5 timeout=300
         ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:7000/api/users
     </Location>
     
     
 </VirtualHost>
```

Tried adding a **Limit** but I get an error saying it is not allowed in virtual host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/users(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/api/users(.*)$  http://localhost:5000/api/users$1  [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/users(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/api/users(.*)$  http://localhost:7000/api/users$1  [P]
```